# How to reproduce this stylistic z-transform symbol from Phillips et al

Tags: symbols

The text "Digital Control Systems Analysis and Design" by Phillips et al. uses this symbol for z-transforms

[image]

Zooming in it looks like this

[image]

Lastly, if I copy the symbol I get "픃". How can I create this symbol in LaTeX or one that looks like it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to considerate the full package of `mtpro2`. The first `z` is very close to that of the image.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[mtpccal,mtphrb,zswash,mtpscr]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
\[E(z) = \mathbscr{z}[\{e(k)\}] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e(k) z^{-k}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also the option with `dutchcal`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bm,dutchcal}

\begin{document}

$\bm{\mathbcal{z}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this [document](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) you can found all the stylistic z-transform symbol that they are close with your image.

PS: The printing book it is of 1995

[image]

and there is the font Bookman Old Style (evident!!!) and Times (New Roman).

[image]

Probably the `z` is obtained from a font that does not belong to `LaTeX`. **The book, in my opinion, was not written, therefore in LaTeX**.

Comment: +1. When using the `mtpro2` package with the options ` zswash` and `mtpscr`, one could replace `\bm{\mathscr{z}}` with `\mathbscr{z}`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you so much for assigning +1 and for your suggestion. You are great!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming a super-exact replica of the "curly-z" glyph shown in the OP's screenshot isn't needed, the following approach may be of use.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman clone text and math fonts
\usepackage[scr=dutchcal,scrscaled=1.05]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
\[
E(z) = \mathscr{z}[\{e(k)\}] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e(k) z^{-k}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly the same, but without proprietary fonts. And there's no need to waste a math group for just a single glyph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% from mathalpha.sty
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{dutchcal}{\skewchar\font=45 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{dutchcal}{m}{n}{
  <-> s*[1] dutchcal-r}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{dutchcal}{b}{n}{
  <-> s*[1] dutchcal-b}{}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ztr}{% z-transform
  \text{\usefont{U}{dutchcal}{b}{n}z}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
E(z)=\ztr[\{e(k)\}]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e(k)z^{-k}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might want to use `{m}` instead of `{b}` in the `\DeclareMathOperator` code to get

[image]

Change the factor in `s*[1]` to, say, `s*[1.2]` if you want a bigger glyph or `s*[0.9]` for a smaller one. Here's the output with `{b}` and `s*[0.9]`

[image]